# Material Design Floating Action Button requires app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (mine is)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design, android-theme

I added a floating action button to my activity, but I'm getting an error and a crash every time I open that activity.  The error is:

```
E/UncaughtException: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

Which seems obvious, right?  Make my app theme a descendant of Theme.MaterialComponenets.  But I did that and the error didn't go away.

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/edittext_style</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

the relevant portions of the **KMainActivity2**

```
class KMainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

  private val handler by lazy { Handler() }

  private val mainActivityViewModel by lazy {
    getViewModel { MainActivity2VM(application) }
  }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kmain2)
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)
    Logger.addLogAdapter(AndroidLogAdapter())
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
    setupBinding()
  }
}
```

The portions of my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="watch.trigger.android">

  <application
    android:name=".TriggerWatch"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
      android:name=".ui.main.KMainActivity2"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

**The full stacktrace**

```
2020-06-21 13:12:04.263 6505-10240/? E/Finsky: [560] the.a(9): Unexpected experiment flag type found for flag ContentSync__settle_delay
    com.google.android.flib.log.WhatATerribleException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [B to atie
        at afdp.b(PG:3)
        at com.google.android.finsky.utils.FinskyLog.b(PG:5)
        at the.a(PG:9)
        at the.j(PG:2)
        at hah.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at arsr.a(PG:2)
        at arst.run(PG:9)
        at aruw.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at kqv.execute(PG:1)
        at arux.execute(PG:1)
        at arsp.b(PG:20)
        at arsp.a(PG:16)
        at arsp.b(PG:27)
        at arss.a(PG:3)
        at arst.run(PG:12)
        at aruw.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at kqv.execute(PG:1)
        at arux.execute(PG:1)
        at arsp.b(PG:20)
        at arsp.a(PG:16)
        at arsp.b(PG:27)
        at arvn.a(PG:2)
        at aruq.run(PG:11)
        at arvo.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at kqs.run(Unknown Source:14)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [B to atie
        at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2446)
        at the.a(PG:8)
        at the.j(PG:2) 
        at hah.a(Unknown Source:6) 
        at arsr.a(PG:2) 
        at arst.run(PG:9) 
        at aruw.run(Unknown Source:7) 
        at kqv.execute(PG:1) 
        at arux.execute(PG:1) 
        at arsp.b(PG:20) 
        at arsp.a(PG:16) 
        at arsp.b(PG:27) 
        at arss.a(PG:3) 
        at arst.run(PG:12) 
        at aruw.run(Unknown Source:7) 
        at kqv.execute(PG:1) 
        at arux.execute(PG:1) 
        at arsp.b(PG:20) 
        at arsp.a(PG:16) 
        at arsp.b(PG:27) 
        at arvn.a(PG:2) 
        at aruq.run(PG:11) 
        at arvo.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at kqs.run(Unknown Source:14) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
2020-06-21 13:12:04.335 2058-2080/? E/system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2020-06-21 13:12:04.413 2058-2058/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/watch.trigger.android-zFcVqi_RP-07ZaTuYABaZw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:256)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:370)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1941)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:541)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:908)
2020-06-21 13:12:04.414 2058-2058/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/watch.trigger.android-zFcVqi_RP-07ZaTuYABaZw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:256)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:370)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1941)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:541)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:908)
2020-06-21 13:12:04.435 6505-10240/? E/Finsky: [560] the.a(9): Unexpected experiment flag type found for flag ContentSync__settle_delay
    com.google.android.flib.log.WhatATerribleException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [B to atie
        at afdp.b(PG:3)
        at com.google.android.finsky.utils.FinskyLog.b(PG:5)
        at the.a(PG:9)
        at the.j(PG:2)
        at hah.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at arsr.a(PG:2)
        at arst.run(PG:9)
        at aruw.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at kqv.execute(PG:1)
        at arux.execute(PG:1)
        at arsp.b(PG:20)
        at arsp.a(PG:16)
        at arsp.b(PG:27)
        at arss.a(PG:3)
        at arst.run(PG:12)
        at aruw.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at kqv.execute(PG:1)
        at arux.execute(PG:1)
        at arsp.b(PG:20)
        at arsp.a(PG:16)
        at arsp.b(PG:27)
        at arvn.a(PG:2)
        at aruq.run(PG:11)
        at arvo.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at kqs.run(Unknown Source:14)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [B to atie
        at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2446)
        at the.a(PG:8)
        at the.j(PG:2) 
        at hah.a(Unknown Source:6) 
        at arsr.a(PG:2) 
        at arst.run(PG:9) 
        at aruw.run(Unknown Source:7) 
        at kqv.execute(PG:1) 
        at arux.execute(PG:1) 
        at arsp.b(PG:20) 
        at arsp.a(PG:16) 
        at arsp.b(PG:27) 
        at arss.a(PG:3) 
        at arst.run(PG:12) 
        at aruw.run(Unknown Source:7) 
        at kqv.execute(PG:1) 
        at arux.execute(PG:1) 
        at arsp.b(PG:20) 
        at arsp.a(PG:16) 
        at arsp.b(PG:27) 
        at arvn.a(PG:2) 
        at aruq.run(PG:11) 
        at arvo.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at kqs.run(Unknown Source:14) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
2020-06-21 13:12:04.444 10301-10301/? E/trigger.androi: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-06-21 13:12:04.633 6900-6979/? E/MicroDetectionWorker: Stale runnable..ignoring
2020-06-21 13:12:05.547 1807-2098/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2020-06-21 13:12:05.547 1807-2098/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2020-06-21 13:12:05.955 10432-10432/? E/ProcessService: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-06-21 13:12:06.094 10301-10463/watch.trigger.android E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(342)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2020-06-21 13:12:06.148 10301-10463/watch.trigger.android E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(342)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2020-06-21 13:12:09.186 2439-3287/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2020-06-21 13:12:11.908 1940-1940/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-06-21 13:12:12.029 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-06-21 13:12:14.646 2058-2086/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-06-21 13:12:19.055 10301-10301/watch.trigger.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: watch.trigger.android, PID: 10301
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{watch.trigger.android/watch.trigger.android.ui.main.KMainActivity2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:695)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:174)
        at watch.trigger.android.ui.main.KMainActivity2.onCreate(KMainActivity2.kt:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2020-06-21 13:12:19.056 10301-10301/watch.trigger.android E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:203)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.<init>(ExtendedFloatingActionButton.java:144)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.<init>(ExtendedFloatingActionButton.java:138)
            ... 28 more
2020-06-21 13:12:19.119 10301-10301/watch.trigger.android E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{watch.trigger.android/watch.trigger.android.ui.main.KMainActivity2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84 in watch.trigger.android:layout/activity_kmain2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:695)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:174)
        at watch.trigger.android.ui.main.KMainActivity2.onCreate(KMainActivity2.kt:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2020-06-21 13:12:19.119 10301-10301/watch.trigger.android E/UncaughtException: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:203)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.<init>(ExtendedFloatingActionButton.java:144)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.<init>(ExtendedFloatingActionButton.java:138)
            ... 28 more
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: edited and added the full stacktrace

Comment: Which version of material components library are you using?

Comment: com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01

Comment: Could you please show your ExtendedFloatingActionButton xml code?